# C++ KOALA graph library - understanding syntax to access a data structure

Tags: c++, templates, graph, operator-overloading

I am using the [C++ graph library KOALA](http://koala.os.niwa.gda.pl/api/description.html) to calculate the minimum cut of a graph.

This is the example that I am using - [example](http://koala.os.niwa.gda.pl/api/examples/flow/example_Flow.html). It just creates a graph with capacities on the edges and calculates the min cut.

My question is in relation to this line:

```
Flow::minEdgeCut(g, cap, s, t, Flow::outCut(blackHole, edgeIter()));
```

Here is the [document for the arguments of the function](http://koala.os.niwa.gda.pl/api/classKoala_1_1FlowPar.html#a1c8bee436fdbf91f58ee920c7b610f59).

It says that it returns the edges that the minimum cut goes through. It prints the edges immediately with the `std::cout` but I need to access them later in the program. My question is how do I access the data structure that they are stored in to for example print them at a later stage.

The example passes the `stuct edgeIter` as an argument to `outCut`. `edgeIter` provides 3 overload operators. Do I need to add an additional member to this stuct?

```
struct edgeIter {
    void operator=(MyGraph::PEdge e) { cout << e->info; }
    void operator++() { }
    edgeIter &operator*() { return *this; }
};
```

Here is the definition of the `outcut` method also.

```
/** \brief Auxiliary class to represent the edge cut. (output structure) */
    template< class VIter, class EIter > struct OutCut
    {
        VIter vertIter;/**<\brief Insert iterator  to the container with vertexes (accessible from starting vertex after the cut)*/
        EIter edgeIter;/**<\brief Insert iterator to the container with edges of the cat.*/
        /**\brief Constructor*/
        OutCut( VIter av, EIter ei ): vertIter( av ), edgeIter( ei ) { }
    };

/**\brief Generating function for the OutCut object.
 *
 *  \tparam VIter the type of insert iterator to container with vertices.
 *  \tparam EIter the type of insert iterator to container with edges.
 *  \param av the insert iterator to container with vertices.
 *  \tparam ei the insert iterator to container with edges.
 *
 *  [See example](examples/flow/example_Flow.html). */
template< class VIter, class EIter > static OutCut< VIter,EIter > outCut( VIter av, EIter ei )
    { return OutCut< VIter,EIter >( av,ei ); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edgeIter` is an instance of an [`OutputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator). You can adapt the code to use a [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) and collect all results in a vector `edges` as follows:

```
std::vector<MyGraph::PEdge> edges;
Flow::minEdgeCut(g, cap, s, t, Flow::outCut(blackHole, std::back_inserter(edges)));
```

There is also a `front_inserter`, or you can write a custom implementation like `edgeIter`.